# ElasticSearch - Should I Shard by Partition?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster of 80mm documents with 4 data nodes and 3 master nodes. Searching in the cluster is pretty fast depending on the query, but is always painfully slow to scroll when I need to pull millions of documents out at once.

I do have logical partitions in my data, and only search on a given partition at a time (client id). Though these partitions don't necessarily have an even distribution of documents. One partition may have 1mm documents while another only has 100k.

For this reason I never considered partitioning my shards since I'm certain it wouldn't be an even distribution.

Is my thinking correct or could I see faster query/scroll times by keeping partitioned data localized to a shard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome of routing depends on the use case, but if applied correctly it can make the difference between a hard working cluster or a performant one.

With [routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) enabled, write and search operations will hit only the single shard which is relevant according to the routing parameter. It will reduce the impact on many layers of the cluster like distribution of requests, network traffic, threads/IOPS on the nodes, merging the results etc.

But the data will be distributed unevenly across the shards associated with the index. You'll potentially get highly loaded shards on the one side and barely used shards on the other side. Also the optimal size for a shard (40-50GB) will be violated by the same reason. For small shards there will be to much overhead handling the shard in comparison to the data being held by the shard. And for large shards there will be to much data to search though.

In order to overcome this downside, there is another [option for routed indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#routing-index-partition): Increase the partition size. All routed requests will go to a larger partition, not a single shard but a subset of available shards. This will reduce the risk of imbalanced shards while reducing the search impact. Just set `index.routing_partition_size` while creating the index to a value larger `1` but lower than `index.number_of_shards`. Now the requests will be routed across shards in the partition rather than one (basic routing) or all shards (no routing) in the index. It's a reasonable trade-off between route-optimized reading and balanced data distribution.

I see another potential improvement: With routing enabled, there will be still more than one logical partition (the client in your case) per shard and irrelevant data have to be visited while searching. That's why you should think about using [index sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/index-modules-index-sorting.html) in order to improve reading speed in the underlying segment files of a shard. This feature is available with or without _routing. Having all associated data stored together will help you to reduce search speed too. But it comes at costs of writing speed because the documents have to be ordered for flush or segment merge operations.

Here is a example index creation request using it all together, assuming your most common case is writing and reading the data routed using client_id and mostly querying for specific order_id:

```
PUT my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 10, 
            "routing_partition_size: 2,
            "sort.field": ["client_id", "order_id"],
            "sort.order": ["asc", "desc"] 
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
       ...
    }
}
```

This answer has been written while 7.5 was the current version of elasticsearch.